# Merge migrations in entity-framework-core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to merge all migrations files into one ?

I created initial migration.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

[Source](http://benjii.me/2016/05/dotnet-ef-migrations-for-asp-net-core/)

When ever I have some model change I create new migration update.

But now I have too many migration update files.
Is ti possible to merge all migration files to one ?

Off course drop database is not an option, I have to preserve data !

Comment: Makes no sense, your database could be in **ANY** of the migration states. i.e if you have 6 migrations and your db is at migration 4,but if you merge merge 3 to 6 into one migration file, you can't never upgrade your db which is on the 4th migration

Comment: Best thing you could do is that if you have 15 migrations, rollback to migration 2, then create a new migration. But that still has problems above if your app runs on more than one server which are on different state (you can never roll back further than the oldest migration that is in use)

Comment: To address the concerns in the above comments, just bring all databases to the latest migration first. Then, delete all migration script files, including the model snapshot (important). I would then delete all records in the __EFMigrationsHistory table and add a new one that has the name of the single migration file you create. This is the way to preserve all data in all tables too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

EF 6.X has a option `IgnoreChanges`. That is the perfect fit for your scenario. But unfortunately it is not a feature available in EF core.

But there is a workaround.

**Step 1 :** Delete all the migration scripts in the Migrations folder.

**Step 2 :** In the package manager console : run

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

**Step 3 :** Delete both `Up()` and `Down()` methods code. Before you do this, keep those methods saved elsewhere as we will need them again in step 5.

**Step 4 :** run:

```
 PM> Update-Database
```

It'll insert a new record into `__EFMigrationsHistory` table.

**Step 5 :** After that fill the above migration script's (i.e. `.._InitialCreate`) `Up()` and `Down()` method from the content kept in a safe place from **Step 3**.

That is it. Now you have only 1 migration file :)

**Note :** EF core with Package manager console (PM) :[**Package Manager Console**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell)

Comment: I am just not sure if is possible to run migration in entity-framework-core from package manager console. I couldn't. I had to done this from command prompt.

Comment: you can.please see the doc here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: please see the **Note** also.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It must clearly specify that this is a bad idea and should only be used in a test environment with caution prior to applying it to a production environment .

Comment: I would also like to add that if someone does this they need to make sure they have the correct default project selected in the package manager console. :)

Comment: Instead of "Delete both Up() and Down() methods code" in step 3 you can just comment out  the `Up()` method and then un-comment it in final step 5.

Comment: I agree that's not a good solution but with a project that evolve years over years, you may have hundreds migrations. and that's not a good solution too.

Comment: The best solution I used was working in database first (with edmx and/or database project). I didn't understand why Microsoft removed this option. More efficient (you can really fine tune your database for perfs), less issues when deploying to new server (just publish a database project to SQL server or generate a script to do that in 2 sec), EDMX model keep your code model and database in synch, ...

Comment: Db first is not gone per se. The EDMX visual designer was buggy and not really necessary. It's spiritual successor in EF Core is Scaffold-DbContext which beautifully reverse engineers entity models from an existing database's schema. This also makes it easy to go code-first from an existing database. If a database exists solely to serve an application, then code-first is the better option, particularly for deployment. Without code-first migrations, changes have to be made to the app and db separately when promoting to staging/production.

Comment: That approach seems to lose raw SQL statements like `migrationBuilder.Sql()` used within `Up()` or `Down()`

Comment: I have to add to additional steps on order make it work. After completing step 5, I had to delete the one entry in History table and then run the update-database command, only then all my tables were recreated

Comment: Steps 3, 4, and 5 can be replaced by simply deleting all records from __EFMigrationsHistory table and adding a new one that has the exact file name without its extension you created with Step 2. The version in the ProductVersion field is not important, so you can add the one you have in the last record or get it from the NuGet package.

Answer (score 8):

When you want to merge not all but N last migrations, the protocol is not the same:

1. Revert N last migrations, *one by one*, each with the 2 following commands:

   - `dotnet ef database update NameOfTheLastMigration`
   - `dotnet ef migrations remove`
2. Apply reverts to database:

   - `dotnet ef database update`
3. Create the "merge" migration:

   - `dotnet ef migrations add NameOfTheMergeMigration`

Comment: Reverting will delete all columns you have added, including the data in them.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do that is removing all migration files physically and adding new one. If your migrations are in "Migrations" folder, you can simply delete it, otherwise you need to delete your "ModelSnapshot" file too. I think this approach can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow .NET C# developer I concluded that EF migrations were rather poorly designed to interface with source control as they store large binary schema data per migration (bad for source control systems) and cause unending grief when trying to merge migrations from multiple GIT branches (bad for team workflow). So I eventually ditched EF migrations and replace them with something much simpler that would also work with both GIT merges and our DBAs (who only cared for SQL).

I chose the FOSS app MyBatis / Migrate that works with any JDBC supported SQL engine. I've used it with SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle (not Postgres yet). I've also used it with C# / EF projects (I just stopped using EF's migrations). It's a no-brainer so great for novice coders. No dependencies so ok to use for **any** SQL database project with **any** application language. Since it's pure SQL you can leverage features specific to your SQL dialect (e.g. In MySQL, you can add a new column after any existing column using the MySQL specific AFTER clause rather than be forced to add it at the end of the table).

You just create timestamped SQL scripts (using their `migrate new` command) that contains both forward and rollback SQL code for your schema or data migration. Using filenames prefixed with timestamps (instead of version numbers) means your software teams can easily create and later merge multiple migrations files from different git branches - too easy! They just get combined and applied to the database as part of a single release.  If you do need to perform complex data migrations you can either code a stored procedure OR you can code a Java class as part of a migration (although this won't help your DBAs).

For DBAs who don't want to deal with VS or .NET, you can use the `migrate script` command to generate either a forward or rollback SQL script that gathers the sequence of migrations to be applied to a given software release.

You can configure multiple database instances (e.g. development, test, stage, prod) and just select which one you want to apply your SQL migration to using the `--env` option (e.g. `--env=stage`). In each database instance it creates a `CHANGELOG` table that tracks the migrations that have been applied.

To get started ... Install Java JDK 8 and then install this app.

- https://mybatis.org/migrations/

Examples:

```
$ migrate status   #  Shows migrations applied and "pending" (be applied) to the selected database 
$ migrate up 1     # Applies the next migration
$ migrate down 1   # Undo the last migration 

$ migrate redo 1   # Undo and apply last migration (handy when developing migrations)

$ migrate up       #  Applies all pending migrations 

$ migrate --env=test status   # Show status of the `test` database.

# Emit forward and reverse SQL for a sequence of migrations. 
# Just what your DBAs wanted!
$ migrate script 20090804225207 20090804225333 > up.sql    
$ migrate script 20090804225333 20090804225207 > down.sql
```

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**MyBatis Schema Migrations** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c45AevIuYGk)

If you'd prefer to stick with C# code you might want to have a look at [Fluent Migrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/). It's particularly good for product projects where you need to support multiple database platforms. I've used it project that supported both SQL Server + MS-Access.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I find the most efficient and easier way to do it:

1. Apply the last migrations if not already.
2. Remove all rows from the *_EFMigrationsHistory* table from your database
3. Remove the Migrations folder from your project.
4. Create a new Migration either with package manager console or dotnet ef cli
5. Copy the name of the Freshly created migration (Without extension) and insert it as a new row in the *_EFMigrationsHistory* table along with your dotnet ef tool version.